# drawable-nodpi stretching 9-patch

Tags: android, nine-patch

I'm trying to use a 9 patch image on a button in Android. I have it in the `drawable-nodpi` folder so it should use the same image for any resolution and not stretch it. If that's the case I'm totally mystified as to why this would happen:

[Looks fine in the GUI in Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xaqyk.png)

[But in the simulator...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klk4E.png)

It seems to be stretching the image even though its in the `drawable-nodpi`, any idea why this is happening?

[This is my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuSbS.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely at the bottom of your image, it looks as if there is some drop shadow in the same line as the bottom 9-patch black line.
This will cause your 9-patch not to work.

Did you create the 9 patch in Android's 9 patch creator? This will make sure such things will not happen

Comment: Wow I didn't even notice that... I wasn't using the 9-patch creator but I definitely will from now on!